# How to find paragraph bounding box coordinates in a scanned document?

Tags: opencv, neural-network, statistics, imagemagick-convert, connected-components

I'd like to get the coordinates of all areas containing any text in scans of documents like the one shown below (in reduced quality; the original files are of high resolution):

[image: Example input image]

I'm looking for something similar to these (GIMP'ed-up!) bounding boxes. It's important to me that the paragraphs be recognized as such. If the two big blocks (top box on left page, center block on right page) would get two bounding boxes each, though, that would be fine:

[image: ![Example of a possible desired result]

The way of obtaining these bounding box coordinates could be through some kind of API (scripted languages preferred over compiled ones) or through a command line command, I don't care. What's important is that I get the coordinates themselves, not just a modified version of the image where they're visible. The reason for that is that I need to calculate the area size of each one of them and then cut out a piece at the center of the largest.

What I've already tried, so far without success:

- ImageMagick - it's just not meant for such a task
- OpenCV - either the learning curve is too high or my google-foo too bad
- Tesseract - from what I've been able to garner, it's the one-off OCR software that, for historical reasons, doesn't do Page Layout Analysis before attempting character shape recognition
- OCRopus/OCRopy - should be able to do it, but I'm not finding out how to tell it I'm interested in paragraphs as opposed to words or characters
- Kraken ibn OCRopus - a fork of OCRopus with some rough edges, still fighting with it
- Using statistics, specifically, a clustering algorithm (OPTICS seems to be the one most appropriate for this task) after binarization of the image - both my maths and coding skills are insufficient for it

I've seen images around the internet of document scans being segmented into parts containing text, photos, and other elements, so this problem seems to be one that has academically already been solved. How to get to the goodies, though?

Comment: I do not understand the issue. If you specify `convert image -crop WxH+X+Y +repage result`. Then you should get just the region you specified. Any outside border should not matter. Are you cropping a very large area. I thought your question was about cropping a small area to get some particular word. Please clarify.

Comment: The question is not about how to crop, it's about how to decide what to crop. I've hundreds of these and each is different. Many have text toward the center of the image, but by far not all. So how to figure out what's a good area for cropping?

Comment: @fmw42, is my question still unclear to you? I'd love to modify it so it becomes easier to understand, but I'm not sure what about it might be unclear...

Comment: I do not have a good solution for you to avoid any large border effect such as what you show. If you know the size of the area that you want, then you can create a template of some say 5% gray below white and then use Imagemagick compare to find the best match in the larger image. But if you do not know the size of the region you want, then I do not have a good solution at this time. I will think about it.

Comment: CONTINUED: But I still do not understand how you are deciding which piece of text you want to extract.

Comment: I've changed the question around to show what I've tried today. Is what I'm trying to achieve also clearer now?

Comment: The question has undergone another rewrite and still no answer. Is it better/customary in such cases to close the question and open a new one? Or to keep working on the question? Hoping for some feedback as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I did not down-vote the question, but now that you have more clearly explained it and I have answered it, I up-voted your question, so that it is now back to 0.

Comment: Thank you, @fmw42 :-)

Also, finally finding the time now to play around with the values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you can threshold the image to keep from getting too much noise, then blur it and then threshold again to make large regions of black connected. Then use `-connected-components` to filter out small regions, especially of white and then find the bounding boxes of the black regions. (Unix bash syntax)

```
convert image.png -threshold 95% \
-shave 5x5 -bordercolor white -border 5 \
-blur 0x2.5 -threshold 99% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=20 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
+write tmp.png null: | grep "gray(0)" | tail -n +2 | sed 's/^[ ]*//' | cut -d\  -f2`
```

This is the `tmp.png` image that was created. Note that I have discarded regions smaller than 20 pixels in area. Adjust as desired. Also adjust the blur as desired. You can make it larger to get bigger connected regions or smaller to get closer to individual lines of text. I shaved 5 pixels all around to remove spot noise at the top of your image and then padded with a border of 5 pixels white.

[image]

This is the list of bounding boxes.

Here is the listing:

```
267x223+477+123
267x216+136+43
48x522+413+0
266x86+136+317
266x43+136+410
266x66+477+404
123x62+479+346
137x43+142+259
117x43+486+65
53x20+478+46
31x20+606+347
29x19+608+48
26x18+716+347
26x17+256+480
25x17+597+481
27x18+716+47
21x17+381+240
7x7+160+409
```

We can go one step further an draw boxes about the regions:

```
boxes=""
bboxArr=(`convert image.png -threshold 95% \
-shave 5x5 -bordercolor white -border 5 \
-blur 0x2.5 -threshold 99% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=20 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
+write tmp.png null: | grep "gray(0)" | sed 's/^[ ]*//' | cut -d\  -f2`)
num="${#bboxArr[*]}"
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
WxH=`echo "${bboxArr[$i]}" | cut -d+ -f1`
xo=`echo "${bboxArr[$i]}" | cut -d+ -f2`
yo=`echo "${bboxArr[$i]}" | cut -d+ -f3`
ww=`echo "$WxH" | cut -dx -f1`
hh=`echo "$WxH" | cut -dx -f2`
x1=$xo
y1=$yo
x2=$((xo+ww-1))
y2=$((yo+hh-1))
boxes="$boxes rectangle $x1,$y1 $x2,$y2"
done
convert image.png -fill none -strokewidth 2 -stroke red -draw "$boxes" -alpha off image_boxes.png
```

[image]

Increase the threshold-area from `20` a little more and you can get rid of the tiny box on the lower left side around a round dot, which I think is noise.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive, just using ImageMagick! The tiny boxes are not problematic at all as I'm looking to calculate box area size and then choose the largest box. What is problematic is that the shadow between the left and the right page is being detected as well. I'll play with the threshold a little to see if that can make it go away. If not, I'll have to discard anything that's much taller than it is wide, first.

If it's okay, I'd like to wait a while before accepting the answer in order to see if something that "understands" the difference between "shadow" and "text" comes along, too.

Comment: Just test the box to throw out the very tall thin box, i.e, nearly the full height of the page and whatever width you think is appropriate that falls in the middle of the two-page image.

Comment: One tiny thing: why do you follow `grep "gray(0)"` up with `tail -n +2`? Was that meant to get rid of "Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):" at some point?

Comment: Also, in case you're interested, this is what your code does to the full-resolution image with no tweaks of any of the values applied: https://i.imgur.com/wU9iBTw.png ... if someone was trying to do OCR with Tesseract, this might possibly be a real nice preparation for that.

Comment: Didn't take a lot of experimentation. This is what I'm going to go with: https://i.imgur.com/I1oN4hR.png (shave 100x100, border 100, blur 0x7.5). I'll update the question again once I've finished calculating the biggest landscape-oriented square.

Comment: In the first code I presented, I did use -tail to skip the header, but that was redundant. In the second code I presented,  I did not use -tail -n +2, because the grep "gray(0)" automatically removes that header. You can also replace `+write tmp.png null: | grep "gray(0)" | sed 's/^[ ]*//' | cut -d\  -f2`)` with `+write tmp.png null: | awk '/gray\(0\)/ {print $2}'`, which does the same thing but using AWK

Comment: For a larger scale image, you would need to increase the blur value to close the spaces between lines.

Comment: Hmm, is that not what I did? In any case, I'm still mighty impressed by the result and have made a mental note to read up a little on Graph Theory and Connected Components.

Comment: Yes, you did it correctly by increasing blur. I was just point that out as the main issue that needed adjusting.